# When Start Emulator is display this error and eclipse close?

Tags: android, eclipse, 64-bit, runtime-error

i have just format everything and copy the all required sources but
when i run any project in eclipse is going close and this error is displayed i don't understand why this error display

```
i am using eclipse kepler 64 bit
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java was started but returned exit code=13 eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763583/java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13-eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must change to java 64 bit.
[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763583/java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13-eclipse)

Comment: thanks for the help but got the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763583/java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13-eclipse