# Eclipse ADT - java was started but returned exit code = 13

Tags: java, eclipse, adt

my eclipse adt i use to program in android is not opening. I have read a lot of possible solutions like [Can't start Eclipse - Java was started but returned exit code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13) 
but that didn´t work either. I have tried to change the PATH variable of my pc to both jre or jdk and still got the error. I have tried to use on the .ini file both jdk and jre but no luck either.

Eclipse ADT is showing me this: [image: eclipse error code 13]

Here is the error:

My .ini file is this:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-Declipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

my java version is 1.7.0_25

my JAVA_HOME is C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7
my PATH is c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: last time i saw this, i restarted my pc, then its solved.

Comment: I already shut down my PC many times, so I don´t think it works. Do you mean restart intead of shutting down? What difference will it make?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20763583/1689695

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11461607/1689695 . Duplicate question

Comment: did you add `;` at the end of your java path?
something like C:\xxx\xxx\x;C:\xx\x; <- a ';' at the end

Comment: Also, shouldn't the / characters be \ in the path: C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin? I was under the impression that \ is the path separator character for windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use a 64-bit Eclipse (indicated by the `org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64` plug-in) and a 32-bit Java (indicated by its install path being under `Program Files (x86)`). They have to match. Using the 32-bit ADT bundle is probably the easier fix.

Answer (score 0):

Change the shortcut pointing in your C:\programdata\oracle\java\javapath to point to your 64-bit versions

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow below steps :

1. Make sure that you have Eclipse 64 bit version.
2. Download and install the 64-Bit Java version form here http://www.java.com/download/manual.jsp.
3. Add the following two lines to your `eclipse.ini` file (just before the “-vmargs” line):
   `-vm
   c:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe`

or sometimes `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\` will also work.